# Adding Legend Entry results in a error for the code below?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Please note the \addlegendentry commands in the following code. The moment I enable them, it results a error which I am not able to handle. How do I correctly construct the legend for this graph which works otherwise?

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.60000,0.20000,0.00000}%
\definecolor{mycolor2}{rgb}{0.87059,0.49020,0.00000}%
\definecolor{mycolor3}{rgb}{0.63529,0.07843,0.18431}%
\definecolor{mycolor4}{rgb}{0.74902,0.74902,0.00000}%
%
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=10cm,
height=8cm,
%at={(2.679444in,1.170889in)},
scale only axis,
separate axis lines,
every outer x axis line/.append style={black},
every x tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}},
xmin=5,
xmax=40,
xlabel={Variance of each entry of $\mathbf{C}_i$  in dB --------\textgreater},
xmajorgrids,
every outer y axis line/.append style={black},
every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}},
ymin=5,
ymax=26,
ylabel={Average Number of Users --------\textgreater},
ymajorgrids,
title={Average Number of Users v/s SINR for Different Algorithms},
legend style={legend pos=north east,draw=black,fill=white,legend cell align=left, font=\small}
]
\addplot [color=blue,solid,line width=3.0pt,mark size=7.1pt,mark=square,mark options={solid},forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
5   14.3\\
15  14.44\\
30  14.46\\
40  14.48\\
};
%\addlegendentry{N=4; L=15; Comb};
\addplot [color=red,solid,line width=3.0pt,mark size=6.7pt,mark=triangle,mark options={solid},forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
5   14.22\\
15  14.34\\
30  14.34\\
40  14.34\\
};
%\addlegendentry{N=4; L=15; EVP};
\addplot [color=mycolor1,solid,line width=3.0pt,mark size=6.7pt,mark=triangle,mark options={solid,rotate=90},forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
5   12.5\\
15  12.3\\
30  11.92\\
40  12.2\\
};
%\addlegendentry{N=4; L=15; ConRel};
\addplot [color=mycolor2,solid,line width=3.0pt,mark size=10.0pt,mark=x,mark options={solid},forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
5   22.46\\
15  22.38\\
30  23.22\\
40  22.88\\
};
%\addlegendentry{N=4; L=25; Comb};
\addplot [color=mycolor3,solid,line width=3.0pt,mark size=17.3pt,mark=diamond,mark options={solid},forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
5   21.9\\
15  21.82\\
30  22.88\\
40  22.52\\
};
%\addlegendentry{N=4; L=25; EVP};
\addplot [color=mycolor4,solid,line width=3.0pt,mark size=6.7pt,mark=triangle,mark options={solid,rotate=270},forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
5   18.8\\
15  18.36\\
30  18.54\\
40  18.82\\
};
%\addlegendentry{N=4; L=25; ConRel};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: The code doesn't compile even without the `\addlegendentry` because of a missing `\begin{document}`. While you're editing the question, could you please also remove all the code that isn't necessary for reproducing the problem (the custom colors, all those `axis` options, ...)

Comment: I have edited it. It compiles for me now. I am sorry but I am not actually sure which is or isn't necessary owing to my rudimentary skills in tikz. I tried removing some of them as you requested which again results in further errors.

Comment: The error is caused by the `forget plot` keys, they're used precisely to exclude plots from the legend.

Comment: Yes. That corrected it. The code was generated from a GUI program. I forgot to add legends while I was working on the GUI. Though I went back to the GUI and corrected it. I was curious which piece of code is actually hindering it from manually adding latex code for legends. Please write your reply as an answer.

Comment: Finding out which is necessary is something you do by creating a Minimum Working Example. (Or Minimum non-Working Example.) You don't need particular skills to make one - just a little patience ;).

Comment: @Jake Do you want to write-up an answer?

Comment: @TeXnician: I've added an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error (`Missing } inserted.`) when trying to use `\addlegendentry` is caused by the use of the option `forget plot`. This option is used to exclude the plots from the legend, which collides with the command `\addlegendentry`.

Removing `forget plot` from the plot options fixes the problem.